# How to encrypt particular values in a property file using openssl or gpg

Tags: encryption, openssl, password-encryption

I wanted to know how I can go about encrypting particular values in a properties file using openssl or gpg.

Most of the examples seem to consist of the below I have seen seem to encrypt the entire file. But I just wanted to use it to encrypt stored passwords.

To Encrypt

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in un_encrypted.data -out encrypted.data
```

To Decrypt

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in encrypted.data -out un_encrypted.data
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use `openssl` to encrypt any string you want:

```
$ echo 12345678901 | openssl enc -e -base64 -aes-256-cbc -k MySecretPassword
U2FsdGVkX18z9p14y9XRhDdRBRoeJfIkdLQXQmGfKag=
```

In your case you could use a bash script like this:

```
encrypted=`grep "the.name.of.my.property" myFile.properties|cut -d'=' -f2|openssl enc -e -base64 -aes-256-cbc -k MySecretPassword`
sed "/the.name.of.my.property=/ s/=.*/=$encrypted/" myFile.properties > newFile.properties
```

This will produce a new file named `newFile.properties` with the encrypted field.

Comment: sorry could you clarify how the properties file is accessed and then value within it is encrypted?

Comment: Do you know exactly the name of the property that you want to encrypt?

Comment: yes I do it is somethling along the lines of example.trust.password=1234

Comment: do I delete the old properties file which isn't encrypted? The reason is that won't the password still be accessible via the unencrypted file?

Comment: No you don't delete the old file with just this code, however you can easily add a command that delete your old file

Comment: how would you decrypt this btw as the value is taken and encrypted and put into a separate file?